# Python Pandas concate dataframe - NaN instead of values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a strange problem when merging 2 dataframes. Although both dataframe contain values along the whole index, the merged on has only shows values in one column, e.g. for one of the orginal dataframes.
Please see the pictures below for clarification:
[image: Single Dataframes]

[image: Merged dataframe]

As you can see, the index is the same and there are values. I tried to merge, concat and append but I always have the same issue.

Does anybody of you have a clue?
Thank you very much in advance!
Sebastian

Comment: Can you post raw data and code rather than screenshots, you can modify the output by doing `pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', False)`

Comment: It may also be better to perform a merge in your case: `df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')`

Comment: At this point it shouldn't make a difference but I can't help you unless you post data and code that allows me (and others) to reproduce your problem

Comment: Possibly you have to specify the axis keyword? `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simple `concat` would work for you.

```
data1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
data2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

concat_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

The key is `axis=1` which will concatenate the data frames horizontally rather than vertically.

The output looks like:

```
    0   0
0   2   1
1   4   3
2   6   5
3   8   7
4  10   9
5  12  11
```